# Download file from node js server to android app

Tags: android, node.js, arcore

I am developping an augmented reality app.
I am facing a problem when I want to get the GLB file from my node server to display it with augmented reality .
I tried many solution but no one of them helped me...
the question is how to load this GLB file from node js server
Example : 127.0.0.1/products/downlods/file.glb
(this link returns the glb file)
I want to create A file in android appp from it

Comment: You cannot create files in Android apps. You only can create files in the storage of your Android device.

Comment: You can read this file as a stream and cache it in device and you can use library like `volley` implementing this.